# Gulp. Copy from FTP

Tags: ftp, gulp, copy, backup

How can I download files from FTP via gulp into local dir?
Code below doesn't work:(

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
ftp = require('vinyl-ftp');

gulp.task('FtpBackup', () => {
    var conn = ftp.create(ftpConnections['cloud'][0]);
    gulp.src(conn.src('/wwwroot/Debug'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('BackUp/'))
});
```

There is:
**ftpConnections['cloud'][0]** - object with connection settings:

```
{
host: 'someHost',
port: 'somePort',
user: 'someUser',
password: 'somePass',
parallel: 10,
log: gutil.log
}
```

Gulp log:

```
[13:58:07] CONN
[13:58:07] 'FtpBackup' errored after 32 ms 
[13:58:07] Error: Invalid 
glob argument: [object Object]   at Gulp.src
(C:\Work\...\node_modules\vinyl-fs\lib\src\index.js:20:11) at Gulp.gulp.task
(C:\Work\...\gulpfile.js:190:10) at module.exports
(C:\Work\...\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:34:7) at gulp.Orchestrator._runTask
(C:\Work\...\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:273:3) at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep
(C:\Work\...\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:214:10) at Gulp.Orchestrator.start
(C:\Work\...\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:134:8) at C:\Users\snowil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\lib\versioned\^3.7.0\index.js:46:20 at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)   at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)   at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:577:11)   at startup (node.js:160:18)   at node.js:456:3

[13:58:07] READY 
[13:58:07] MLSD  /wwwroot 
[13:58:07] MLSD  /wwwroot/DebugSurvey 
[13:58:07] DISC
```

Comment: I tried get it via ftp-client, but it doesnt "understand" config to connecting. All what I saw : connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:21 however config looks like in code above. (sry for my Eng)

Comment: I connected to ftp, but ftp-client doesnt support automatic recurs download all subfolders in folder :( Can anyone help me?